# Approve content aggregator app itunes

Tags: xcode

Hi
I've built an IOS app that has a tab bar and extracts content from a website and displays it.
I need it to be approved in itunes but when i sent it to review they replied

"We've completed the review of your app but cannot post this version to the App Store because it is only a content aggregator and provides a limited set of features and functionality to users"

I've read about it and i noticed that there are a lot of apps just like my app that are used by news sites and they were approved.

My content must be on a remote web server due to security reasons and i have complied with the reachibility protocol that apple requires which means that i monitor if there is network available on the device and warns the user that the content can only appear on connected ipad.

Is there a way that i can add approve my app or must i become a large news site in order to make my app approved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add searching or filtering of the content displayed in your app. That should do the trick.

Comment: hi @Niels, How can i add a simple search that will show results from the website that is opened in the view?

Comment: Asuming that your content is itemized. Add a search field at the top of your screen and only display news items that contain the keywords from the search box. Cache the selected keywords between launches of the app so the user can personalize the displayed content.